# php parsing and whitespacing error

Tags: php

```
echo "<OPTION value=$data2['product_id']>$data2['product_id']</OPTION>";
```

This gives me the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Can you help me out please? How do I fix this error?

Comment: @madhu : please validate an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<OPTION value=".$data2['product_id'].">".$data2['product_id']."</OPTION>";
```

Comment: echo '<select name="pid" >';

while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<OPTION value=".$data2['product_id'].">".$data2['product_id']."</OPTION>";
}
echo "</SELECT>"; this should ideally show the product ids as drop down list but it isnt showing. canu  help?

Comment: `echo '<select name="pid">';
while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
 echo '<OPTION value="'.$data2['product_id'].'">'.$data2['product_id'].'</OPTION>'; 
} 
echo '</SELECT>';`

Comment: thanks but its still not showing

Comment: What does `var_dump($data2);` show ?

Comment: So your request can be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
echo "<OPTION value=$data2[product_id]>$data2[product_id]</OPTION>";
```

or

```
echo "<OPTION value={$data2['product_id']}>{$data2['product_id']}</OPTION>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The error can be removed by wrapping the variables inside curly braces:

```
echo "<OPTION value={$data2['product_id']}>{$data2['product_id']}</OPTION>";
```

Though this would be better (escaping output):

```
echo '<option value="', 
  htmlspecialchars($data2['product_id']), '">', 
  htmlspecialchars($data2['product_id']), 
  '</option>';
```

Comment: No, one of the two escapings is wrong.

Comment: @Cranio care to explain which one?

Comment: 1. Use `htmlspecialchars()` to filter text input values for html input tags.  i.e.,

`echo '<input name=userdata type=text value="'.htmlspecialchars($data).'" />';`

 
2. Use `htmlentities()` to filter the same data values for most other kinds of html tags, i.e.,

`echo '<p>'.htmlentities($data).'</p>';`

Comment: Well maybe "wrong" was too much, shouldn't have been so rude and explain better, sorry :)

Comment: Why htmlentities? Why would I want to convert for example `å` into `&aring;`  if my document is in a character encoding supporting `å`?

Comment: @Cranio Thanks for explaining, though I fail to see how one is better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
echo "<OPTION value=$data2[product_id]>$data2[product_id]</OPTION>";
```

or

```
echo "<OPTION value=" . $data2['product_id'] . ">" . $data2['product_id'] . "</OPTION>";
```

or

```
echo sprintf("<OPTION value=%s>%s</OPTION>", $data2['product_id'], $data2['product_id']); // separate logic from presentation
```

You *must not* use quotes when referring to an associative or numeric array inside a double-quoted string.

I suggest though that you **do use** quotes in HTML attributes, and use `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()` for `value="..."` and the text inside `OPTION` as a general best practice.

Comment: @madhu You're welcome. Please Upvote all your favourite answers and accept the best one to keep the site alive.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [`printf`](http://php.net/printf) (or [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf)) instead of putting variables inside strings because I think it's much easier to read. You'll probably also want to HTML escape the value using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to avoid errors if the value contains `<` or `>`.

```
$prodid = htmlspecialchars($data2['product_id']);
printf('<OPTION value="%s">%s</OPTION>',
       $prodid,
       $prodid);
```

Comment: or `echo sprintf()` if you use `echo` instead of `print`.

Comment: Salman, `echo sprintf` is kind of a redundant pattern.

Comment: I too have written `echo sprintf`, but it was just to show that you can store the result in a variable and manipulate it. As for itself with no context it's right that it is redundant.

Comment: Less redundant: `printf('<OPTION value="%1$s">%1$s</OPTION>', $prodid)`

Comment: I'm not sure if I like the "less redundant" version. `printf` can lead to somewhat over-engineered patterns sometimes, but it is nice to know that it's possible!